# Openswan established NATed tunnel but, I can't ping remote end's lan PC

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

I am establishing site to site tunnel.

```
192.168.2.0/24===10.103.6.40<10.103.6.40>---10.103.6.1...10.103.6.29<10.103.6.29>===192.168.1.0/24;
```

Local ip: 10.103.6.40

Local lan: 192.168.2.0/24

Remote lan is behind 10.103.6.29 (router) has lan 10.1.1.0/24.

Remote ip: 10.1.1.44 (Behind 10.103.6.29, I have enabled VPN Passthrough)

Remote lan: 192.168.1.0/24

Now, Tunnel is established, but i can not ping remote lan's machine on 192.168.1.2.

Log of ipsec:

```
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: listening for IKE messages
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface br0/br0 192.168.2.1:500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface br0/br0 192.168.2.1:4500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface eth3/eth3 10.103.6.40:500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface eth3/eth3 10.103.6.40:4500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:4500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: adding interface lo/lo ::1:500
Mar  4 16:34:45 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: initiating Main Mode
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG daemon.err ipsec__plutorun: 104 "NG" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Openswan (this version) 2.6.38 ]
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=115 
Mar  4 16:34:46 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal)
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike (MacOS X): peer is NATed
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: received Vendor ID payload [CAN-IKEv2]
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: Main mode peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '10.103.6.29'
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I3 to state STATE_MAIN_I4
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_128 prf=oakley_md5 group=modp1024}
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #1: Dead Peer Detection (RFC 3706): enabled
Mar  4 16:34:47 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #2: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+PFS+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK {using isakmp#1 msgid:f5d74d20 proposal=AES(12)_128-MD5(1)_128, AES(12)_192-MD5(1)_128, AES(12)_256-MD5(1)_128, AES(12)_128-SHA1(2)_160, AES(12)_192-SHA1(2)_160, AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160, 3DES(3)_192-MD5(1)_128, 3DES(3)_192-SHA1(2)_160 pfsgroup=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024}
Mar  4 16:34:49 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #2: Dead Peer Detection (RFC 3706): enabled
Mar  4 16:34:49 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #2: transition from state STATE_QUICK_I1 to state STATE_QUICK_I2
Mar  4 16:34:49 NG authpriv.warn pluto[9431]: "NG" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP=>0x9143bd7d <0x1cb79f9a xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_MD5 NATOA=none NATD=10.103.6.29:4500 DPD=enabled}
```

Tunnel is established successfully.

local configuration (At 10.103.6.40 side):

```
config setup
    nat_traversal=yes
    oe=off
    protostack=netkey

conn NGpassthrough
    left=192.168.2.1
    right=0.0.0.0
    leftsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    rightsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    authby=never
    type=passthrough
    auto=route

conn NG
    right=10.103.6.29
    rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
    left=10.103.6.40
    leftsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    leftnexthop=10.103.6.1
    auto=start
    leftid=10.103.6.40
    rightid=10.103.6.29
    #x_rightdynamic=yes
    authby=secret
    compress=no
    failureshunt=drop
    dpddelay=15
    dpdtimeout=60
    dpdaction=restart
    pfs=yes
    ike=aes128-md5-modp1024,aes192-md5-modp1024,aes256-md5-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes192-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-md5-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024,aes128-md5-modp1536,aes192-md5-modp1536,aes256-md5-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes192-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha1-modp1536,3des-md5-modp1536,3des-sha1-modp1536,aes128-md5-modp2048,aes192-md5-modp2048,aes256-md5-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes192-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,3des-md5-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp2048
    esp=aes128-md5,aes192-md5,aes256-md5,aes128-sha1,aes192-sha1,aes256-sha1,3des-md5,3des-sha1
```

Remote Configuartion (At 10.1.1.44 side):

```
config setup
    nat_traversal=yes
    oe=off
    protostack=netkey

conn NGpassthrough
    left=192.168.1.1
    right=0.0.0.0
    leftsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
    rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
    authby=never
    type=passthrough
    auto=route

conn NG
    right=10.103.6.40
    rightsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    left=10.1.1.44
    leftsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
    leftnexthop=10.1.1.1
    auto=start
    leftid=10.103.6.29
    rightid=10.103.6.40
    #x_rightdynamic=yes
    authby=secret
    compress=no
    failureshunt=drop
    dpddelay=15
    dpdtimeout=60
    dpdaction=restart
    pfs=yes
    ike=aes128-md5-modp1024,aes192-md5-modp1024,aes256-md5-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes192-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-md5-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024,aes128-md5-modp1536,aes192-md5-modp1536,aes256-md5-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes192-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha1-modp1536,3des-md5-modp1536,3des-sha1-modp1536,aes128-md5-modp2048,aes192-md5-modp2048,aes256-md5-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes192-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,3des-md5-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp2048
    esp=aes128-md5,aes192-md5,aes256-md5,aes128-sha1,aes192-sha1,aes256-sha1,3des-md5,3des-sha1
```

Firewall rule on 10.103.6.29:

```
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.44:500 
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.44:4500
```

I have two pc's at both end. On local side PC has ip 192.168.2.2 and at remote side PC has ip 192.168.1.2.

I CAN PING REMOTE ROUTER (192.168.1.1) but, can't access/ping remote lan PC (192.168.1.2).

Help me please.

Comment: Brijesh, please don't forget, that ICMP Echo functionality which ping uses is not somthing that is always available. It's quite common for various distribution to disable it for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Leonid for reply. But I have checked this with FTP, SSH, and other telnet service too. Nothing is working. I have checked my network there is no security policy applied.